# First time Pathfinder GM and I want to make an animal companion one shot

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions, game-design, one-shot

This is an odd question, but I figured y'all could help me. I have been playing Pathfinder and DnD for years, but I have never created my own one shot. I am creating a high-level one shot for my brother's birthday, and I am not exactly sure what to do but I have this idea that I really want to make work because it sounds super fun.

I am planning on requiring all players to create a character that has an animal companion, be it a witch, druid, etc, and then due to some unfortunate circumstance I want the people to be kidnapped and I want the players to play as their animal companions.

How would y'all suggest making this work? I know animal intelligence is super low, so the animals would really only be able to track the team via trails left somewhere. I was thinking of fudging the rules somewhat and having a house rule to allow magical beasts as companions, if the character levels are high enough. But I am not sure.

What do y'all think? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The site can't answer really answer questions like this (i.e. "What do you think?"). However, the site *can* answer a question like *What issues must I keep in mind when designing this adventure?*… which, I think, may be the actual question. Feel free to edit the question to say so, or if there's a different question about designing this adventure that's more pressing, ask that instead. Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Do the players' "characters" even matter if they're going to be kidnapped and they're going to be playing as animal companions?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to over complicate  the scenario for your first attempt at being the GM?  *I was thinking of fudging the rules somewhat and having a house rule to allow magical beasts as companions* Why do you feel that this is necessary?

Comment: All close-votes so far are "Opinion-based." I think instead we need more detail, details as outlined by Korvin.